# How to filter over key value pair to get desired csv output?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have this json input payload as follow:

[
{
"": 1,
"name": "apple"
},
{
"": 274,
"name": "tablet"
},
{
"": 782,
"name": "tv"
},
{
"": 2,
"name": "mobile"
}

]

I wanted an output in csv with separator pipe delimiter.

Desired output:

product|qty
apple|1
tablet|274

Thank you

Comment: Which records should be filtered out? what is the criteria for the filter? Is the key for the quantity really an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume based on the output that you only want the records for name equal to "apple" or "tablet".

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator="|"
---
payload
    filter (["apple", "tablet"] contains $.name)
    map {
        product: $.name,
        name: $.""
    }
```

Output:

```csv
product|name
apple|1
tablet|274
```

Comment: that’s answered my requirements appreciate that!